# aiohttp returns empty cookie after using google identity services

Tags: python, google-apps-script, cookies, aiohttp

I migrated Google Sign-In JavaScript platform library to Google Identity Services. After successful login in Safari macOS, my `aiohttp` server sets cookie `myid=10` that is used by the server. Unfortunately when I read cookie `request.cookie.get('myid')`, it returns `None`. The issue is that google adds cookie `g_state={"i_l":0}`. Aiohttp uses `http.cookies.SimpleCookie` to process `Cookie` header and when `g_state` comes before my cookie in `Cookie` header, I get `None`. I created a simple script to reproduce the issue:

```
from http.cookies import SimpleCookie
cookie = 'g_state={"i_l":0}; myid=10'  # prints empty
cookie = 'myid=10; g_state={"i_l":0}'  # prints Set-Cookie: myid=10
print(SimpleCookie(cookie))
```

I tried Python 3.6 and 3.10. They print the same result. As for workaround, I read `myid` from `request.headers['Cookie']` and the server works. But what is the correct fix? Is it Google bug with invalid cookie value or SimpleCookie that cannot process valid cookie or aiohttp bug?

Answer (score 0):

It's not an `aiohttp` issue, it's malformed cookie and a bug in `SimpleCookie`

https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/92936